# How can I launch an independent activity to my application as well as the application of phone launches the activity to make calls?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm working on an application and I need to make it possible to launch an activity in a separate history and stack as you can see in the photo that the application of the telephone starts the activity to make calls that works independently and even this can be observed when I want See recent apps.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  Show the intent that you are using to start your activity.

Comment: For the moment I only use the conventional form: "Intent in = new Intent (getActivity (), ActivityB.class);
                         In.addFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                         In.addFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                         StartActivity (in); ".
But I can not accomplish what I explain in my question with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Manifest file for your application

In the <activity> element

Add an attribute: android:process=".*ProcessName*"

This will cause that particular activity to be launched in a new process.

For more details, search for "android:process" on  [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

in activity node

details here:

[Using the manifest file](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html#ManifestForTasks)

[Using Intent flags](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html#IntentFlagsForTasks)

Answer (score 0):

For creating a separate and independent history and stack, you need to set these flags :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,ActivityA.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
                  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

In this manner, you have two sets of activities, with their own separate listing in the recent apps list.